# Font files cannot be loaded when using CDN in Magento?

Tags: cdn

When I use CDN for my Magento site, there is a problem that font files cannot be loaded? I don't know why it does happen. 
Is there any solution to overcome this issue?

Comment: which magento version you are using and how are you loading the CDN elaborate please?

Comment: any error messages?

Answer (score 0):

Ask your linux admin or server team or the support team from where you have purchased the CDN to exclude the font files from the CDN.

They didn't work together.
In some of my projects as well, I faced the same issue and based on the recommendations from the designers or the design, I excluded fonts from the CDN.

I guess you are using fonts from some third party like google or something else.